# LINQ lambda expression query to join more number of table with different where condition

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, expression

First I have to filter the value based on the **Condition** value in `Table1`.
Then I have to join another table called `Table2` from `Table1`. Those two tables have common field **Condition2**.

At last I should get the value based on the **Final condition** by joining the `Table2` and `Table3` common condition (Final_Condition) satisfied values.

I have used below query to get the data. But I got the cross joined result.

```
var result = db.Table1
    .Where(m => m.u.Condition == "Condition")
    .Join(db.Table2, u => u.Number, uir => uir.Number, (u, uir) => new { u, uir })
    .Where(m => m.u.Condition2 == m.uir.Condition2)
    .Join(db.Table3, proposal => proposal.uir.ID.Leasing_Proposal_Id, prop => prop.ID,
        (proposal, prop) => new
        {
            proposal.u,
            proposal.uir,
            prop
        })
    .Where(m => m.uir.FinalCondition == m.prop.FinalCondition)
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Select(m => new Model
    {
        Name = m.Name,
        Id = m.Id,
        Dept = m.Dept
    })
    .Where(m => ((m.Name != null) ? m.Name.ToUpper().Contains("xxx") : false))
    .Cast<IResult>()
    .ToList();
```

Comment: *Why* are you using joins in LINQ instead of specifying relations and navigation properties in your ORM? By using LINQ to join you lose almost all benefits LINQ provided over SQL.

Comment: Can you write this as one SQL statement? Then you can convert it to a LINQ query. Of course, if you can do that, you can create a VIEW with that SQL and map an entity to that view

Comment: Is there any other way to do this by using LINQ. Because i have to get the selected values with various conditions

Comment: Do what? You haven't actually explained what you want, only how you thought the solution would look like. All this code does *NOT* help to explain the problem. It actually makes it harder. One can't even *see* the tables involved in all this

Comment: Please define the tables with (only) the significant properties and their relations (one-to-many? many-to-many?). Furthermore: what is your goal?

Comment: Why are you joining to `db.Table2` on `Number` if `Condition2` is the common field?